# Firebird-Time Interval- between 2 Dates

Tags: date, firebird

I try to select the period of employment for the members in a Company.

Example: 
Date of join: 01.01.2001
Today: 27.02.2014
Now, I want this:
13 years, 1 month and 27 days

I have a Statement which works on MSSQL, but I cant translate it to firebird-SQL.

Could anybody help me?

Thx

Erik

Comment: To get the number of days between two days simply subtract them: `date '2014-02-27' - date '2001-01-01'`

Comment: yes, but the result will be 4800 days... thats not what it should be.. I want to have 13 years, 1 Month an 27 days, u know?

Comment: Show us the MSSQL statement which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively green Firebird n00b here w/a fair PostgreSQL background, although specialized GIS work focused mostly to DB design and the sourcing/cleaning/making spatial multi-source data sets (usually of dubious quality) and then querying for map-able results in answer to specific location riddles. Toolbox is light, therefore, on Admin/Optimization/3rd Party Application Setup etc. You may (err, will) see some Firebird specific questions from me in the coming weeks. Thanks in advance!
Took a stab at this slightly older Firebird question to get a feel for the new-to-me flavor of date handling and concatenation. Took more tweaking & testing than expected & my dabbling may not be the most efficient/elegant solution but, assuming the existence of column **join_date** in table **employees**, this will work:

```
SELECT Y ||' Years, '|| M ||' Months, and '|| D ||' Days'
FROM
(
SELECT
CASE WHEN datediff(year, join_date, current_date) <> datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365
THEN datediff(year, join_date, current_date)-1
ELSE datediff(year, join_date, current_date)
END as Y,
CASE WHEN datediff(year, join_date, current_date) <> datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365
AND datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)<0
THEN datediff(month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, join_date, current_date)-1, join_date), current_date)-1
WHEN datediff(year, join_date, current_date) <> datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365
AND datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)>=0
THEN datediff(month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, join_date, current_date)-1, join_date), current_date)
WHEN datediff(year, join_date, current_date) = datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365
AND datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)<0
THEN datediff(month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)-1
ELSE datediff(month, dateadd(year, datediff(year, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)
END as M,
CASE WHEN datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)<0
THEN datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date)-1, join_date), current_date)
ELSE datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)
END as D
FROM employees
)
```

The subquery turned conditional on me when it became clear that: a) calculations on year & month don't consider the date as a whole; and b) date subtraction will happily return negative values regardless of the order of events.

Year/Month/Day Example: datediff() returns a value of 1 when retrieving the number of days, months, or years between 31.12.2015 and 1.1.2016.

Negative Value Example: about 69% of my test-date values are less than zero when I calculate the number of days *less the number of days contained by whole months* using:

```
SELECT datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, date_column, current_date), date_column), current_date) as D FROM date_table
```

We can streamline the subquery if substituting 365 days for one year is acceptable. The trick works with my test data but may trigger pitfalls with a broader range of dates. The simplified query looks like:

```
SELECT Y ||' Years, '|| M ||' Months, and '|| D ||' Days'
FROM
(
SELECT
datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365 as Y,
CASE WHEN datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)<0
THEN datediff(month, dateadd(year, datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365, join_date), current_date)-1
ELSE datediff(month, dateadd(year, datediff(day, join_date, current_date)/365, join_date), current_date)
END as M,
CASE WHEN datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)<0
THEN datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date)-1, join_date), current_date)
ELSE datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, join_date, current_date), join_date), current_date)
END as D
FROM employees
)
```

Holler if I goofed it or if I employed bad/overwrought logic. Hope it's helpful to someone at some point! Keep a lookout for new Firebird questions (might already have locked in struggle with a JDBC connection string that
just
will
not
lose).

Thanks and hello again!
--Rob

*I never had a plan--* Anonyman

Answer (score -2):

```
YEARS=DATEDIFF(YEAR FROM :BEGIN_DATE TO :END_DATE);
MONTHS=DATEDIFF(MONTH FROM :BEGIN_DATE TO :END_DATE);
DAYS=DATEDIFF(DAY FROM :BEGIN_DATE TO :END_DATE);
```

Comment: Although a correct answer, it's probably better if you include a complete SQL statement that can be executed directly rather than just a code fragment.

Comment: I don't think the answer is even correct - it doesn' t split the response into x years, y months and z days which the OP wants. It provides the number of years, then the number of months (which will be ~157) and the number of days ((13* 356) + (1 * 30) + (27)).